# I am using dispatch for scala, how can I convert the response of the web service into sa JSON file?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I am making a http request to a web service using the dispatch library and scala. Everything is working fine, what I wanted to do is to convert the response into a JSON. I can already get the response but it's in a String format. Here's what I'm doing:

```
 val http = new Http

 val handler = http(req.as_str)
```

req is a Request variable containing the URL.

Thanks for the help. :D

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborate a bit. What is a request (case class, list, map, ...)? What do you intend to do with the JSON representation?

Answer (score 0):

If your request is a case class, you can use [Lift-Json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/) to serialise a case class tree into a json string (and back). Other such (de)serialisers exists, for exampe, [sjson](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson/wiki/Examples-of-Type-Class-based-JSON-serialization), but I've only worked with Lift-Json so far.

Comment: In other classes, I used the scala.util.parsing.json library in creating json, will it work if I use it with dispatch?

Comment: AFAIK, ``scala.util.parsing.json`` only allows parsing JSON strings into JSON objects. Hence, you would first have to serialise a request into a string, and then deserialise it back into a JSON object. That's neither efficient nor elegant.